# Spring Boot with Spring Security OAuth2 and Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to figure out how to use Spring Security OAuth2's `@EnableResourceServer` while leaving the default Spring Boot's actuator security un-touched.  I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1 with the default versions of the dependencies.  I have the following configured

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity 
public class OAuthConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .mvcMatchers("/resource/{type}").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resource/data/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

I'm not explicitly configuring any of the other security settings.  I *thought* the actuator endpoints would continue to be appropriately secured but I'm getting 401 and when checking with the security debug log it doesn't show anything regarding HTTP Basic.  Any i doing something wrong?  some other configuration i need?

Comment: what url are you requesting? i would expect .antMatchers("/<actuatorurl>/**").permitAll()

Answer (score 0):

Id expect something like this -

```
@Override
public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll()
    .mvcMatchers("/resource/{type}").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/resource/data/**")
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: I was at least hoping that I wouldn't need to explicitly setup the security for the actuator (I have that all under /about).  The problem is the actuator security is setup differently per actuator endpoint.  For instance, the `/health` endpoint is publicly available, but the `/metrics` isn't and I'd rather not (if possible) go re-do all that security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to application properties the management roles, something like this `management.security.roles=ROLE_SOMEROLENAME` your user should hold this role to be able to access the actuator endpoints. You may also set the path for the actuator endpoint using this property `management.context-path=/myactuator`